# How to turn google maps url into an iframe-friendly url

Tags: php, google-maps

This is a sample url:

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Barnes+%26+Noble+Booksellers+86th+%26+Lexington/@40.7747314,-73.9653734,15z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1sBarnes+%26+Noble,+5th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY,+United+States!3m1!1s0x0:0xdec8ade72ab827a7

This clearly does not work:

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Barnes+%26+Noble+Booksellers+86th+%26+Lexington/@40.7747314,-73.9653734,15z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1sBarnes+%26+Noble,+5th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY,+United+States!3m1!1s0x0:0xdec8ade72ab827a7"
</iframe>
```

How to turn the sample url into a url that works for the iframe? I don't even have to use iframe. I just want to integrate google maps by using urls supplied in the format listed above.

I'm using PHP, if that matters.

Comment: Is it good enough to go to the URL, click the cogwheel, "Share and embed map" and get the iframe with URL from the "Embed map" tab?

Comment: @Ondkloss Probably not. :(

Comment: So you want to automate this process (you are doing it many times), and always get the link in that format?

Comment: @Ondkloss Yes, the users enter simply the url in their browser window. I can't make them enter the embed thing.

Comment: Is using an Google Maps API (with the associated key limitations) ok?

Comment: @Ondkloss Yes, it's okay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the URL format you provided I would try to transform it to [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) URL. This requires a API key. You had the following URL:

> [https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/**Barnes+%26+Noble+Booksellers+86th+%26+Lexington**/@40.7747314,-73.9653734,15z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1sBarnes+%26+Noble,+5th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY,+United+States!3m1!1s0x0:0xdec8ade72ab827a7](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Barnes+%26+Noble+Booksellers+86th+%26+Lexington/@40.7747314,-73.9653734,15z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1sBarnes+%26+Noble,+5th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY,+United+States!3m1!1s0x0:0xdec8ade72ab827a7)

Transforming it to an embed URL only requires you to extract the address part of the URL you already have. The result will be:

> [https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY&q=**Barnes+%26+Noble+Booksellers+86th+%26+Lexington**](https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY&q=Barnes+%26+Noble+Booksellers+86th+%26+Lexington)

If you alternatively were to receive the URL with no specific place, just a view, it might look like this:

> [https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@**40.7777212,-73.9567045**,**15z**](https://www.google.com/maps/@39.7837935,-93.0754222,16z)

In this example you have to extract the latitude, longitude and zoom level (15z), and create a URL like this:

> [https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=API_KEY&center=**40.7777212,-73.9567045**&zoom=**15**](https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=API_KEY&center=40.7777212,-73.9567045&zoom=15)

Reading the API there are two more modes (search and direction) that can be handled in a similar way, but aren't as likely to be used in your case.

As for the extracting I would probably use regex or search and substring, depending on how varying the URLs you receive are.

Answer (score -3):

**You simply need an embed url**

1. Just Simply type in the address Google/Google Maps
2. Click Share(Just below directions).
3. Select Embed map. Copy/paste the url in your code.