# Embed google map using share url

Tags: html, google-maps

Say, you go to google maps and search for 'Walmart', then choose the first Walmart in the list, and you get a URL like:
`https://www.google.com/maps/place/Walmart+Supercenter/@41.7991677,-70.5882922,10z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1swalmart!3m1!1s0x89e4c6127cc5b685:0x104d337439f46ea9`

then if you go to that URL, it gives you a valid map with the pinpoint. This (above) is the URL that would be stored in my database, thus the URL I want to use to embed a map.

Of course, I can't use that URL to embed in an iframe, and I instead have to use:
`https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d380717.11119594605!2d-70.5882922!3d41.7991677!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89e4c6127cc5b685%3A0x104d337439f46ea9!2sWalmart+Supercenter!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1445294674664`

So...  for any shareable Google Maps url, how can I convert it to an embeddable url to be used as the iframe `src`?

I can do it server-side using PHP or client-side with javascript. use of regex would be acceptable.

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579591/how-to-turn-google-maps-url-into-an-iframe-friendly-url

Comment: No, I must not've been searching well, cuz I didn't see it. Looks like what I needed ('specially the lat/long solution). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could do the trick :

```
$matches = [];

preg_match("/@(.*?),(.*?),/",$str,$matches);

$place = $matches[1];

preg_match("/@(.*?),(.*?),/",$str,$matches);

$lat = $matches[1];
$long = $matches[2];

echo '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q='.$place.'&center='.$lat.','.$long.'&key=AIzaSyAN0om9mFmy1QN6Wf54tXAowK4eT0ZUPrU&zoom=8" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
```

After the first @ char it is located the latitude and logitude, which you can extract using the regex I wrote, and than capture the output on 2 groups and add it that on the embedd URL.

Comment: But what about the other parts (`!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d380717.11119594605!2d` and `!3d` and `!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89e4c6127cc5b685%3A0x104d337439f46ea9!2sWalmart+Supercenter!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1445294674664`)? Won't those change from location to location, too?

Comment: @Jakar I updated my question so you can use this properly, you just need an API key from Maps as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you want to do this conversion and all , but if you are using javascript client side , then you can use [Google maps v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) for javascript

Then you will directly get lat/lng and you can store them and use for all future calls, which seems much cleaner approach.

See the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .controls {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    
    #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 300px;
    }
    
    #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
    }
    
    .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
    }
    
    #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
    }
    
    #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>
    #target {
        width: 345px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
    // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
    // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
    // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

    function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {
                lat: -33.8688,
                lng: 151.2195
            },
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
            searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        // [START region_getplaces]
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        var marker;
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            console.log('place: '+places[0]);
            if(marker!=null)
              marker.setMap(null);

            var icon = {
                url: places[0].icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                // icon: icon,
                title: places[0].name,
                position: places[0].geometry.location
            });
            map.setCenter(places[0].geometry.location);
            //save places[0].geometry.location for all future reference

        });
        // [END region_getplaces]
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

of course if you need you can remove search list and by default always select 1st result.

Answer (score 1):

Client side option:

```js
$(function() {
  var str = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Walmart+Supercenter/@41.7991677,-70.5882922,10z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1swalmart!3m1!1s0x89e4c6127cc5b685:0x104d337439f46ea9';
  var matches = str.match(/\/@([\d\.,-]+)z\//)[1];
  var splits = matches.split(',');
  var lat = splits[0];
  var long = splits[1];
  var zoom = splits[2];
  var url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + lat + ',' + long + '&z=' + zoom + '&output=embed';
  $('#output').html('<iframe style = "width:200px;height:400px" src = ' + url + '></iframe>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output' style="width:200px;height:400px"></div>
```